# Yank command is not working in vim editor

Tags: vim

I want to copy code from `vi` editor to clipboard so that I can paste it in the browser. I know the command <kbd>gg"*yG</kbd> and it's working when I open the code like `vim code.py`, but when I open like `vi code.py`, it doesn't work.

But normally when I type `vi`, it opens `vim`. I thought `vi` and `vim` are same command now, both referring to improved version of `vi` editor. Then why is this happening.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l $(which vi)`? It's possible `vi` is symlinked to a slimmed down distribution of vim such as vim-tiny, which might have been compiled without clipboard support

Comment: Since the result isn't the same when you type `vi` instead of `vim` I bet it can't be the same command

Comment: @ohlec i got this output - lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  3 May 20 10:24 /usr/bin/vi -> vim

Comment: Strange. Maybe you have another vim in your PATH? What does `ls -l $(which vim)` say?

Comment: Also, does the output of `vi --version` include `+clipboard`?

Comment: @ohlec this is the output - lrwxr-xr-x  1 ashu  admin  30 Sep 28 00:06 /usr/local/bin/vim -> ../Cellar/vim/8.1.0400/bin/vim

Comment: yes +clipboard is there

Comment: have you tried aliasing vi to point to vim instead? Try that and see if it works.

Comment: OK, so it looks like your vim was installed via homebrew, while there is still another vim behind the symlink  from vi. What OS are you on? Is there any other difference in the compilation flags you get from `vim --version` and `vi --version`?

Comment: @ohlec yea got it. I'm getting different output for vim --version and vi --version. for vi --version clipboard is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing from your comments, it seems like you have installed two versions of vim; one probably via your OS's installation procedures and one via `homebrew`.

`vi` is symlinked to the default installation, which was compiled without `+clipboard`, while `vim` would execute the binary from homebrew (because that's how your `$PATH` is configured), which with compiled *with* clipboard support.